# Pandas group by date and get count while removing duplicates

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
                                   maid        date  hour  count
0  023f1f5f-37fb-4869-a957-b66b111d808e  2021-08-14    13      2
1  023f1f5f-37fb-4869-a957-b66b111d808e  2021-08-14    15      1
2  0589b8a3-9d33-4db4-b94a-834cc8f46106  2021-08-13    23     14
3  0589b8a3-9d33-4db4-b94a-834cc8f46106  2021-08-14     0      1
4  104010f8-5f57-4f7c-8ad9-5fc3ec0f9f39  2021-08-11    14      2
5  11947b4a-ccf8-48dc-a6a3-925836b3c520  2021-08-13     7      1
```

I am trying get a count of maid's for each date in such a way that if a maid is included in day 1, I don't want to include in any of the subsequent days.  For example, `0589b8a3-9d33-4db4-b94a-834cc8f46106` is present in both 13th as well as 14.  I want to include the maid in the count for 13th but not on 14th as it is already included in 13th.

I have written the following code and it works for small data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('/home/ubuntu/uniqueSiteId.csv')
umaids=[]
tdf=[]
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df=df.sort_values('date') 
df=df[['maid','date']]
df=df.drop_duplicates(['maid','date'])

dts=df['date'].unique()
for dt in dts:
        if not umaids:
                df1=df[df['date']==dt]
                k=df1['maid'].unique()
                umaids.extend(k)
                dff=df1
                fdf=df1.values.tolist()
        elif umaids:
                dfs=df[df['date']==dt]
                df2=dfs[~dfs['maid'].isin(umaids)]
                umaids.extend(df2['maid'].unique())
                sdf=df2.values.tolist()
                tdf.append(sdf)

ftdf = [item for t in tdf for item in t]
ndf=fdf+ftdf
ndf=pd.DataFrame(ndf,columns=['maid','date'])
print(ndf)
```

Since I have 1000's of data frames and most often my data frame is more than a million rows, the above takes a long time to run.  Is there a better way to do this.

The expected output is this:

```
                                   maid       date
0  104010f8-5f57-4f7c-8ad9-5fc3ec0f9f39 2021-08-11
1  0589b8a3-9d33-4db4-b94a-834cc8f46106 2021-08-13
2  11947b4a-ccf8-48dc-a6a3-925836b3c520 2021-08-13
3  023f1f5f-37fb-4869-a957-b66b111d808e 2021-08-14
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: If I understood what you're trying to do correctly, why not just sort the dataframe by `date` and then drop duplicates only by `maid`? It will keep the first occurence of `maid`, which also happens to be the first occurence in time since we sorted by `date` . Then you can use groupby as usual.

Comment: Thank you...the sorting by date and removing duplicates by maid worked on smaller df....will test it on the production one and come back

Comment: you can use `groupby` function on date column and then use `unique()` on maid column to count the unique maid for each date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in the comments, the solution is quite simple: sort the dataframe by `date` and then drop duplicates only by `maid`. This will keep the first occurence of `maid`, which also happens to be the first occurence in time since we sorted by `date`. Then do the groupby as usual.